# Firefox: playing plane mp4 in video element previously used for dash.js & drm results in "Media resource xxx could not be decoded."

Tags: firefox, html5-video, mp4, decoding, dash.js

I am experiencing problems in Firefox (and only Firefox) with the dash.js player implementation:
**Once a video element has been used for DRM content it looks like it refuses to play any other content.** This is needed for showing DRM content but interrupt it to show video ads.
How to reproduce (you can basically skip step 4, 5 and 6, this is just a demonstration that the mp4 works):

1. start Firefox (I am using version 48.02 on Windows 10)
2. go to http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/v2.3.0/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html
3. open the browser console
4. select the video element with videoElement = document.querySelector('video')
5. set the source to a sample video with videoElement.src = "http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4"
6. witness working video. You could skip step 4, 5 and 6. I just wanted to demonstrate that of course firefox can play mp4 files.
7. set the stream source to Axinom -> Axinom multi-drm (1080p) from the dropdown menu
8. hit the blue "load" button in the upper right corner
9. witness DRM protected content playing in Firefox!
10. pause the video
11. clear the video elements source by entering videoElement.src = ''; in the browser console
12. set the stream to a plane mp4 as in step 5. I can not requote this step because I can only post two links in this question. Just do exactly as in step 5
13. witness error message in console: "**Media resource xxx could not be decoded.**"

If you like to, you can add a new video element to the page just by appending it via javascript. This will play the video, while the first one will not. You can destroy the old one, a new one will play it as well.
This does not occur in any other browser. This problem does of course not occur in chrome. Not even in Microsoft edge.

**For my purposes I can not create a new video element.** There is a player build around that and it holds a state. A lot of listeners are registered to the video element. It is not a solution to delete the video element or use a second one.

So, my question(s):

1. Am I doing something wrong in Firefox? How do I clean up my video element to play plain mp4 with it after playing DRM content?
2. Is this a bug? Is it a Firefox bug or a dash.js bug?

Comment: I meant "plain" video element in the title, of course. Because it is very plain and simple. I did not mean "plane". It is not flying. Especially not in the firefox.